# Mocking a static method which calls another static method of the same class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, powermock

I have to write a unit test for a static method which requires mocking another static method of the same class.
Sample code:

```
public class A {
   public static boolean foo(){}
   public static boolean bar(){
       return foo();
   }
}

@PrepareForTest({A.class})
public ATest{
   testMethod(){
       mockStatic(A.class);
       when(A.foo()).thenReturn(true);
       assertTrue(A.bar());
   }
```

}

I have been trying to unit test the bar method but so far not been successful.

**Issue**: Debug doesn't reach the `return foo();` statement in my code and assertion fails. Please advice. I cannot modify the code at this point of time

Any help in mocking the foo method would be appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: And what exact issue do you have with [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockStatic)?

Comment: Even if you can mock static methods, it's really fundamentally a sign that your code is poorly designed.  Design your code for testing rather than the other way around.

Comment: @user3707125 Debug doesn't reach the return foo(); statement in my code and assertion fails. Please advice. I cannot modify the code at this point of time

Answer (score 6):

In this scenario, you should not be creating a mock on class but use `stub` on only that particular method ( `foo()` ) from class `A`,

```
public static <T> MethodStubStrategy<T> stub(Method method)
```

Above method belongs to `MemberModifier` class in API and that is a super class of `PowerMockito` class so your syntax should look like,

```
PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(A.class, "foo")).toReturn(true);
```

Comment: and remember the foo() args, like `A.class, "foo", int.class`

Answer (score 3):

The fact that `false` is the default value for `boolean` played a bad trick. You were expecting that wrong `foo` is called, while in fact `bar` was not called. Long story short:

```
when(A.bar()).thenCallRealMethod();
```